# How to use proxy with basic crawler in apify

Tags: apify

I'm using basic crawler in apify how can I use proxy with this. There is not a option for the proxy in basic crawler or there other way to use proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Basic crawler is basically just a crawling framework without its own capability to request resources so if you want to use it for sure then you'll need to do the requests manually from within the `handleRequestFunction` using some 3rd party request library for Node. Then you can specify the proxy in the library options.

As you can see, unlike with the other crawlers there is no proxy configuration in basic crawler's options: https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/basic-crawler-options

You can use another crawler if you want it to perform the requests on its own and there you can specify proxy in the crawler's options:

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/cheerio-crawler

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteer-crawler

Answer (score 0):

What @vasek-tobey-vicek answered above is valid. But as an implementation guide:

1. You should create your proxy configuration using `Apify.createProxyConfiguration`
2. create your **proxyUrl** like: `const proxyUrl = proxyConfiguration.newUrl();`, where you could also use your **sessionId**
3. use the `proxyUrl` in your request library.

   ex: If you are using the Apify provided `utils.requestAsBroswer` you could provide the `proxyUrl` property in the provided options